# Do Natural Ambition and the two Ki Feats increase your Focus Pool total?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, focus-pool

As a Human Monk, if I choose Natural Ambition as Human Feat, and the two Ki feats as class feats, does it increase my focus pool to 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes.

The text of both of the feats is clear about giving you a focus pool with 1 point in it. However, the call-out box on page 302 of the core rules ("Focus Points From Multiple Sources") tells us that if you gain multiple focus pools, then you add their points together:

> If you have multiple abilities that give you a focus pool, each one adds 1 Focus Point to your pool.

In your example, if you took both *Ki Strike* and *Ki Rush* you would have a focus pool of 2 points.

Be aware that no matter how you do it, the maximum size of a focus pool is 3 points.

Comment: It may be worth noting (or beyond the scope) that they would only be able to replenish 1 spent Focus Point per use (ie if they spend both, they won't get the 2nd back until the next day)